# Alfresco is responding late, taking 3 to 4 minute to get list of workflow

Tags: alfresco

In my alfresco i have 10000 workflows. And when i am getting the list of workflows it is taking 3-4 minutes to show.

When i am hitting the rest service to get user's task it is also taking 5 minute.

My system configurations are:
8 core processor 8 GB RAM for Alfresco

Comment: What rest service are you calling to get the list of workflows?  Can the results be paged?

Comment: If I remember well, there are limitations of Activiti integration in Alfresco. Pagination was not possible back in the day.